# Xamarin Android Archiving Failed: iOS.dll

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin

After a couple of weeks I wanted to put a new alpha version of an app on the google store. (I put 4 versions on the store already without any problems)
But when I try to archive it I get the following (huge) error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void ObjCRuntime.Runtime::set_UseAutoreleasePoolInThreadPool(System.Boolean)' in assembly: 'Xamarin.iOS.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Void System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback::SetDispatcher(System.Func`2<System.Func`1<System.Boolean>,System.Boolean>)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod(MethodReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessEntireQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() Checkk.Android
```

I have the following properties in my Android release:
Linking: SDK assemblies only (If I don't use linking, the app size will become way too big)

Supported-architectures:
Armaebi-v7a & x86

Minimum Android Version: 4.0.3
Target Android Version: 4.03

I changed the version of the app, I have deleted the bin and object folders and cleaned the solution.

Comment: Did you add Xamarin.iOS to your Android App? That won't work.

Comment: @Cheesebaron I selected archive on the android project, I don't know where I can see if I also added the ios to my android app?

Comment: Check your project references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:

```
    switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
     {
     case Device.iOS:
     break;
     }
```

This caused the problem, because after I put it in a comment instead, I didn't get any errors.
So somehow Xamarin doesn't like it when I use this?